# Why use lazy var when adding stackview?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

```
class SummaryLabelTVC: UITableViewCell {
static let identifier = "SummaryLabelTVC"

var summaryIcon = UIImageView().then {
    $0.image = UIImage(systemName: "calender")
    $0.tintColor = UIColor.white
}

var label = UILabel().then {
    $0.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13)
    $0.textColor()
}

lazy var stackView = UIStackView().then {
    $0.axis = .horizontal
    $0.alignment = .leading
    $0.addArrangedSubview(summaryIcon)
    $0.addArrangedSubview(label)
}

private func configureUI() {
    addSubview(stackView)
    addSubview(label)
   
}
```

The first picture is the picture where only the stackView declaration in the code I wrote down is declared with the var keyword, not lazy var.

I don't know exactly the difference between this.
Why is it okay to declare labels or images as var, and only stackview should be declared as lazy var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is not about stack views vs any other kind of view. As the error message suggests, it's about whether you have used any instance members in the initialiser of the property.

In the initialiser of `stackView`, you have used `summaryIcon` and `label`, which are instance members of `SummaryLabelTVC`.

The problem is, if `stackView` is not lazy, `summaryIcon` and `label` might not have been initialised when the stack view's is being initialised, and you would be "adding" uninitialised junk into the stack view. Whatever that will do!

In general, Swift doesn't guarantee initialisation of non-lazy properties happens in the order they are declared. This means that you cannot use other instance properties in the initialisers of instance properties, because they might not have been initialised yet.

By making `stackView` lazy, it is guaranteed that it will be initialised just before your first use of `stackView`. That is what `lazy` means. This means that `stackView` will be initialised *after* all the (non-lazy) instance properties are initialised, because a (first) use of `stackView` cannot occur in one of the initialisers of the (non-lazy) instance properties.

On the other hand, in the initialisers of `summaryIcon` and `label`, you have not used any instance members of `SummaryLabelTVC`, so there are no problems about uninitialised properties there.